# find values in array from another array

Tags: php, arrays

First Array is

```
Array
(
    [2] => Course 1
    [3] => C2
    [4] => COMPUTATIONAL MATHEMATICS -I
    [5] => BASIC ELECTRONICS
    [6] => DATA STRUCTURE
    [7] => COMMUNICATION SKILL
    [8] => SYSTEMS PROGRAMMING 
    [9] => DIGITAL LOGIC 
    [10] => GROUP A:ENGINEERING DRAWING & WORKSHOP
)
```

my second array is

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [course_id] => 2
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [course_id] => 4
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [course_id] => 6
            )
        [3] => Array
            (
                [course_id] => 10
            )
    )
```

my expected result is

```
Array
    (
        [2] => Course 1
        [4] => COMPUTATIONAL MATHEMATICS -I
        [6] => DATA STRUCTURE
        [10] => GROUP A:ENGINEERING DRAWING & WORKSHOP
    )
```

I would like to find out if first array contains value in second array  and return the result array . any idea please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
$firstArray = Array();
    $firstArray[2] = "Course 1";
    $firstArray[3] = "C2";
    $firstArray[4] = "COMPUTATIONAL MATHEMATICS -I";
    $firstArray[5] = "BASIC ELECTRONICS";
    $firstArray[6] = "DATA STRUCTURE";
    $firstArray[7] = "COMMUNICATION SKILL";
    $firstArray[8] = "SYSTEMS PROGRAMMING"; 
    $firstArray[9] = "DIGITAL LOGIC";
    $firstArray[10] = "GROUP A:ENGINEERING DRAWING & WORKSHOP";

$secondArray = Array();
$secondArray[0]["course_id"] = 2;
$secondArray[1]["course_id"] = 4;
$secondArray[2]["course_id"] = 6;
$secondArray[3]["course_id"] = 10;

$result = array(); 
foreach($secondArray as $second){
    $result[$second["course_id"]] = $firstArray[$second["course_id"]];
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this. Define `result` as array. and put second array's values in it by using for loop.

```
$result = array();
foreach($second_array as $sa){
   $result[$sa] = $first_array[$sa];
}

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

@Ronak's answer is the correct idea...the keys for the result just need to reference the course_id, otherwise an undefined offset error occurs.

Sorry, I would have commented but not enough rep yet :)

```
$result = array();
foreach($second_array as $sa){
   $result[$sa['course_id']] = $first_array[$sa['course_id']];
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Vamsi Krishna beat me to it

Answer (score 0):

You need convert to dimensional second array and after use [array_diff_key()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-diff-key.php)